# Featured Image not showing up

Tags: wordpress, html, custom-wordpress-pages

using style attr to show the featured image but the image seems to have 0 height, the image seems to be loaded but with height 0, the whole css code is missing when I inspect

[image]

[image]

```
<?php $featured = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' ); ?>
                    <?php $featured = $featured[0]; ?>
                    <div class="featuredImage" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $featured ?>);"></div>
</header>


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.div featuredImage{
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to open a style tag to write CSS code. Then, fix your CSS selector which is also not correct... Try this:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    div.featuredImage {
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

When you put a `.` before a selector, you are telling the stylesheet it is a class, in your case, `div` is **not** a class, it is a tag, so you just write `div` and then the class name preceded by the `.`.

OR

You could just write `.featuredImage {}`, no need to specify the tag name.

Answer (score -1):

If it's taking height zero, you can add the height attribute yourself along with the background image.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp